# Specific IIS user not working with TLS 1.2

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7.5, tls1.2, windows-server-2008-r2

We have run into a problem with IIS, TLS 1.2 and domain users. I searched SO and other forums, but all possibly related topics didn't lead me to a solution.

Please don't judge the configuration, it wasn't invented by me, I just need to solve this problem.

What happens is the following:

We have an old web application, that opens an executable with Process.Start and that executable calls an external webservice. This used to work fine with TLS 1.0, but in the near future, the external webservice demands TLS 1.2.

So now we are trying to make this work, and we are almost there: we upgraded the executable's .Net Framework version to 4.7.2 and enabled TLS 1.2 on the Windows Server 2008 R2. The web app's .Net Framework version is set to 4.6.1. It seems to me that this should be everything there is to it.

And indeed, when we run the executable stand alone (not called by the web app) from the server, so owned by the domain user logged on to the server (with RDP), everything works as expected; we receive the proper answer from the web service.

Also, when we call the executable by the web app **and** in IIS the application pool identity is set to a build in account: ApplicationPoolIdentity, everything works as expected as well.

But, when we set the application pool identity to a dedicated domain account (so a different one than the one that executed the executable earlier), the trouble begins. Connecting the web service fails with the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint
> listening at https://<some url>/<some webservice name>.asmx that could
> accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
> SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond ...

Now the question is of course, what could be causing this?

I like to believe that the failing domain account is configured correctly, but it seems it is not. Or could it be something else, that I don't even know the existence of...

**EDIT:**

I managed to narrow it down to a permissions issue: when the dedicated domain account runs the application stand alone, it works as it should. When the dedicated account runs it from within the IIS context (started by the web app), it doesn't work, but when the dedicated account is given admin rights, it also works as expected.

That leaves me to the question: what additional permissions does IIS need to allow this setup? Maybe in combination with TLS 1.2 thingies.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not set the application pool identity to the domain user? Can you make sure that the dedicated domain account has permission to run the executed file? No permission to run also return this error because no response is connection failed.

Comment: @BruceZhang The dedicated domain account has some specific permissions that are necessary for other functionality and the 'working' domain account has permissions that should not be set to the dedicated account. Having said that, your suggestion for the permission on the executable is worth investigating indeed, although I would expect a different message. I'll look into that. Thanks

Comment: @BruceZhang the dedicated domain account has the permissions to execute the executable and when running it stand alone it also can use the web service, but it is related to permissions: if we give the dedicated account admin rights, everything works as designed. So, the account can use the web service when running stand alone (which is not by the web app, so not from within IIS context), but when using it from within the IIS context it can't and it is a permissions issue. So the question is now: what does IIS do with permissions?